# How to get all key:value saved in sharedpreference with flutter?

Tags: flutter

Hello I have this function who work's in debug mode but not in release mode ... so I search a solution to perhpas not have this BUG in other way.

```
List<Widget> allkeys;
  get_all() async  {
    final SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();

    setState(() {
      allkeys=prefs.getKeys().map<Widget>((key) {
        return Text(key+ ":" + prefs.get(key).toString());
      }).toList();
    });
}

in debug mode allkeys =["key1:data1 , key2:data2"]
in release mode allkeys =[widget,widget]
```

So I search to just extract all key:value saved with sharedpreference.

if I use only

```
   allkeys = prefs.getKeys();
```

I have a format like that :

```
{key1,key2,value1,value2}
```

I search to have  :

```
`{key1:value1, key2:value2}`
```

Answer (score 0):

finnaly I have change my code like that, it's work even in release mode but I had to change the all regex

```
 allkeys = prefs.getKeys().map<String>((key) {
            return (key + ":" + prefs.get(key).toString());
          }).toList();
        });
```